# string x and int y as parameters of function- Cannot use if (x.length()<y) inside the function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create the following procedure:

```
void something(string x, int y)
{
    if(x.length()<=y)

    etc.
}
```

it compiles but the the computer goes nuts, printing out all kinds of weird symbols, beeping and then crashing.

I believe it's because I cannot use if (x.length() < y) if the x is still unknown which it is since I am creating a procedure.I think I have to convert my string x into a c-string but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What language? How have you called `something()` in your code? How have you created the variables you're passing in?

Comment: C++ is the language sorry about that!

Comment: tagging problem - should specify what programming language are you using

Comment: I'm passing in a string and a number

Comment: sorry guys for the comments I'm new to this and I keep clicking on enter to change lines and I submit half finished comments by accident!! Anyway, the procedure works fine if I don't include this if statement..

Comment: String `x` is not unknown, you've passed it as a parameter to the function. The problem is not where you think it is, you'll have to post more code.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time everyone I'll come back with more info if I make any progress, I realised that the program crashes only for a certain type of string( the string is actually a "getline" from a textfile) for some reason this function doesn't work for my first getline only for the rest...

Comment: Wow, that function really gives away what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's the compare part where things go crazy?

My test program `test`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void something(string x, int y) {
  if(x.length() <= y)
    printf("Length smaller or equal\n");
  else
    printf("Length larger\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string x = "This is a string";
  int y1 = 10;
  int y2 = 20;

  something(x, y1);
  something(x, y2);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ test`, this results in an executable named `a.out`, which, when run, produces the desired output:

```
$ ./a.out
Length larger
Length smaller or equal
```

NB: This is on Ubuntu, but I can't think of a reason why this should fail on e.g. Windows.

Comment: He's asking the wrong question and showing the wrong code but this is a good example of a small concise compiling example he should have given.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably somewhere else than in the posted code. Your assumption that 'I believe it's because I cannot use if (x.length() < y) if the x is still unknown which it is since I am creating a procedure' is wrong, the code is executed after you call the function with specified arguments. Check if your string is properly initialized (which probably is, since you use string class, which initializes to empty string even if you don't assign anything to it).
By the way, the best way to convert std::string to c-string is to use c_str() method of the string class, but it does not solve your problem.